# A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I first searched for this issue on stack & some other sites & implemented solution in web.config file but still getting the error..

My web.config

```
<system.web>    
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,&amp;,:,\,?" targetFramework="4.5.2" requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
      <customErrors mode="Off"/>
      <trust level="Full"/>
    <pages validateRequest="false">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Runtime.Serialization"/>
        <add namespace="System.ServiceModel"/>
        <add namespace="System.ServiceModel.Web"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
```

I am trying to get Iframe source values from my db table. It's google map I want to include in my page..

Comment: What characters you are expecting ? Try  requestPathInvalidCharacters=""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error signals that you are issuing web request with '<' character, and Asp.Net has some prevention against using potentially malicious characters. You should probably set

```
<system.web><httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" /><pages validateRequest="false" /></system.web>
```

See also http://www.christophercrooker.com/use-any-characters-you-want-in-your-urls-with-aspnet-4-and-iis

But keep in mind that you are switching off functionality that exists to make it harder for attackers to break your web application. So, if I were you, I would first think if I can change the app to not use forbidden chars in URLs

Comment: ok. So in my application I need to use google map which gets different values from database. To initiate it inside iFrame then I need to switch on this functionality. In terms of this how can I retain the security of app?

Comment: This error means that your client (browser?) initiates a request that looks like, for example, GET myserver.com /path/<subpath. Then you application does something with '/path/<subpath'? There can be a controller that handles requests on this path, and '<subpath' would be a parameter to this controller (other options are possible, depending on how your application works). Try to understand what logic initiates request to this path? Can you change this logic?